# redirect requests in nginx or Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx

Our Web site is developed by Laravel and is running on Digital-ocean (ngnix).
we are facing an issue about the url's which comes with an extra slash like service/index.php/?parameters=5
and want to remove the slash after index.php
I don't know any thing about ngnix.
only want to remove extra slash and redirect to right url.
wrong url

```
https://example.com/service/index.php/?main=2
```

Right url

```
https://example.com/service/index.php?main=2
```

service is a directory and contains some php files.

Comment: It's called a trailing slash. Perhaps this article is of use to you: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/remove-trailing-slash-in-nginx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open NGINX configuration file For the Website**

If you have configured separate virtual hosts for your website (e.g [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), such as /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf then open its configuration with the following command

```bash
  sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf
```

you can list all website configuration file

```
sudo ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and edit your website file

**Remove trailing slash**

```
server { 
       listen 80; 
       server_name example.com; 
       rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; 
}
```

In the above code, the rewrite statement will redirect all URLs to those without trailing slash.

resource https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/remove-trailing-slash-in-nginx/

Comment: Perhaps you want to elaborate a little more about the steps you took and how you resolved the problem. Generally answers with only a link, or 'link-answers', aren't great answers. For example, what if someone visits this question in a year because they face the same problem, they click the link, and it leads to a 404-error?

Comment: actually by googling about  trailing slash You will get the answer